# Catch event emitted from *class* constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, coffeescript

Is it possible to catch event emitted from *class* constructor? The problem is that it fires before handler is attached. Class code in CoffeeScript:

```
class YtVideo extends events.EventEmitter
    constructor: ->
            events.EventEmitter.call this
            # logic
            @emit 'error', 'Invalid YouTube link.'
```

Example:

```
ytVideo = new YtVideo

ytVideo.on 'error', (e) -> # This doesn't work for events from constructor.
    alert e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that, as you have seen, can you cannot fire `'error'` synchronously in the constructor because you will not have had time to bind an error event handler yet.

Given that, you have two options:

#### 1. Throw and catch a normal exception

```
throw 'Invalid YouTube link.'
```

and

```
try
  ytVideo = new YtVideo
catch e
  alert e
```

#### 2. Delay the error event so you have time to bind the error listener

```
process.nextTick =>
  @emit 'error', 'Invalid YouTube link.'
```